# How to know if AWS S3 is being used by others AWS services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After two years using aws S3, I have many buckets and I don't remember which one is being used and which one is inactive. Sometimes S3 is getting logs from others AWS services such as ELB, cloudwatch and so. My question is there is a way to know if S3 is being created by which user or being used by other service or not.
Thank you very much

Comment: Look at [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html). It's an extra charge to record "data" events, including puts/gets from S3.

Comment: @Parsifal thank you very much. But if it's not initially activated, there is no way to know. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You won't be able to see the usage before activation, but if your goal is to see what's currently using the buckets, you'll get that information after activation.